# What is a good way to prove that the function $\Bbb Z_n \rightarrow \Bbb Z_u \times\Bbb Z_v$ is well defined?

Tags: group-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics, direct-product

Given a function of the type $\Bbb Z_n \rightarrow \Bbb Z_u \times\Bbb Z_v$ ($[x]_n\rightarrow([x]_u, [x]_v)$) where of course $n=u*v$ how can I prove that is a well defined function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f:\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_u\times\mathbb{Z}_v$, $[x]_n\mapsto ([x]_u, [x]_v)$

It might go like this:

To prove that this function is well-defined, we have to check if it really does not matter which representative of the equivalence class we choose.

So let $[x]_n=[y]_n$. Then $x=nk+r$ and $y=nl+r$ with $0\leq r<n$.

Now $f([x]_n-[y]_n)=f([x-y]_n)=([x-y]_u, [x-y]_v)\stackrel{x-y=n(k-l)}{=}([n(k-l)]_u, [n(k-l)]_v)\stackrel{n=uv}{=}([0]_u,[0]_v)$

Comment: We want to check if $[x]_n=[y]_n$ implies $f([x]_n)=f([y]_n)$. $f$ is a homomorphism, so this is equivalent to $f([x]_n-[y]_n)=(0,0)$. You do not need the difference necessarly. You can calculate both $f([x]_n)$ and $f([y]_n)$ seperatly and check if it is the same. In both cases you would get $([r]_u, [r]_v)$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I deleted my comment because I had deduced what you wrote now and I was writing a new comment to see if my deduction was correct.